# How to calculate correlation between number of characters in a string and its length?

Tags: logic, education, computational-mathematics

Compared to what I'm seeing here on the forum I am a total mathematical noob.

I'm solving an algorithmic problem which I know how to solve but there has to be a better and much simpler solution using mathematics.

So a string is considered valid if it contains the same number of characters OR if ONE of the characters from the string is removed.

For example:

`aabbcc` - valid - same number of characters

`aaabbcc` - invalid - number of occurrences of "a" is 3 and for the rest is 2

`abcdefghhgfedcba` - valid - all characters occur 2 times

`abcdfghhgfedcba` - valid - I removed "e" so one character was removed.

`aabbccddeefghi` - invalid - `fghi` each char in this substring occurs only one time so we would have to change it to either `ffgghhii` or a combination of it without one of the letters.

So the bottom line here is that the difference between the average number of characters and a missing character cannot be greater than one, so if all the characters occur let's say 3 times than the missing char count has to be at least 2.

Now, there has to be a correlation I should be able to calculate between the length of the string and the average number of occurrences of a character in the string.
So depending on the length and the average I should be able to calculate a deviation which would indicate if only one character has been removed or more.

I'm sorry if this is very vague but I really don't know how to define the problem in mathematical terms.

Comment: If $\forall \{i,j \}\ n_i = n_j$, where $n_i$ is the number of characters of type $i$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork thanks for answering, and can you give me an example, I'm afraid I'm unable to read your equation (sorry, I'm a total math noob)

Comment: @RayButterworth thanks I edited the post

Comment: All my little note states is:  "For all values of $i$ and $j$, the number of letters of type $i$ is the same as the number of letters of type $j$."